# How to end a file using vbs without starting anything?

Tags: vbscript, terminate

So, I'm trying to make a security system using vbs that would terminate a process.
Ex:
If you see "cmd.exe"
Terminate cmd.exe

I have coded everything except for the terminating part. I have searched many places but all they do is first run that file and then terminate it. I want to terminate the existing running "cmd.exe"

I tried running a batch file that terminates all "cmd.exe" processes but it just terminated itself leaving the other "cmd.exe" open.

Powershell is not an option too because it's one of the process I want to terminate.

Regards,

A Viper

Comment: Please show the code you used in your batch file to terminate all running "cmd.exe" processes.

Comment: Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43959272/edit) and show us what did tried as code until now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Running TaskKill Command with VB Script**

[`TaskKill`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command can terminate all existing processes whose running in same image name. 
For example, if the process you want to be terminated is "cmd.exe", you can use `TaskKill` as below in your script:

```
Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "CMD /C TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe", 0, False
```

Above script is executed using Windows Script Host, which is not a process you want to be terminated, so this should work.